# Run a task in my app once in every month

Tags: android, job-scheduling

In my android app I have created a function that updates some fields in SQLite database, now I run this function manually and it is doing the job, but I want to run this function automatically once in a month. How it is possible.

Comment: use quartz api : http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/  . it is provide so powerful scheduling job

Comment: Check Here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/56326758/1318946

Answer (score 0):

To run your task periodically i recommend you to take a look at it JobScheduler api which is latest and more powerful for scheduling the job take a look at this https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler.html
if  your app targets api >21 you must use jobscheduler if u want to support the lower version take a look at firebase job dispatcher:https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android