# I have a sqlite table and i want to delete a row from that table at the end of each month. Is there a way to do that in Android

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have an SQLite table and I want to run a query at the end of each month to delete a row from the table, is there a way to do so?

Comment: use workmanger and schedule a task every 30 days. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53901179/android-work-manager-how-to-enqueue-jobs-once-a-month

Answer (score 0):

To delete a row just use:

```
    db.delete(String table, 
            String whereClause, 
            String[] whereArgs)
```

ex.

```
    db.delete("yourTable", "yourRow", null);
```

[https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#delete(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[])](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#delete(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D))

Now to recognize the day of the month use Calendar class:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
int dayOfTheMonth = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar#DAY_OF_MONTH